# Can't use <ALL> in where clause

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have as part of my where clause the following

```
WHERE (@ProgramID IS NULL or ProgramID IN (@ProgramID))
      AND (@ProgramName = '<ALL>' OR ProgramName IN (@ProgramName))
```

This always throws a "expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','" when I select 2 or more values from the parameter. If I select the `<ALL>` it works fine, if I select just one value it's fine. If I remove the `@ProgramName = '<ALL>' OR` part it works fine for single or multiple values. Why is this occurring and how can I resolve it? I needed to add the `<ALL>` because the `(Select All)` that is built in is making the report run poorly due to the number of values passed.

I have a dataset populating the values for the parameter and I have added a `UNION` to that so that the  value is present there correctly (It's a single value dataset, not returning anything but the ProgramName).

Comment: How is ProgramName IN (@ProgramName) suppose to work?

Comment: In the select statement it selects the program's name `PI.Program_Name AS ProgramName`. I have another dataset using the exact same query minus all the other select values returning all of the program names to the parameter and allow the user to filter on that.

Comment: The code you posted does not throw that error. Nor does it do what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out what the problem was. It was the use of `=` instead of `IN`. Even though I was using `IN` for the second half of the statement, the `=` forced it to evaluate the `IN` the same as though it were an `=`. Thus, trying to pass it more than one value causes an error.

Revised the statement to the below, and it now works correctly.

```
WHERE (@ProgramID IS NULL or ProgramID IN (@ProgramID))
  AND ('<ALL>' IN (@ProgramName)) OR (ProgramName IN (@ProgramName))
```

Comment: Still waiting for your answer then. I changed this in SSRS and it works. The original code I posted works as I clearly said - when you pass it one value it works. Pass it two values, and it does not work and throws the error I stated. I changed the SSRS to exactly what I just posted here, and it works correctly.

If the answer is so obvious or whatever the explanation, where is it then?